# How to keep NA values with dcast() function?

Tags: r

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,5),
                 y = c("A","B","C","A","B","A","B","D","B","C","D"),
                 z = c(3,2,1,4,2,3,2,1,2,3,4))

df_new <- dcast(df, x ~ y, value.var = "z")
```

If sample data as given above then dcast() function keeps NA values. But it doesn't work with my dataset. So, the function converts na to zero. Why?

How to keep na values?

[ml-latest-small.zip](https://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/)

```
r <- read.csv("ratings.csv")
m <- read.csv("movies.csv")
rm <- merge(ratings, movies, by="movieId")
umr <- dcast(rm, userId ~ title, value.var = "rating", fun.aggregate= sum)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the first example, `fun.aggregate` is not called, but in second case the change is that `fun.aggregate` being called.  According to `?dcast`

```
library(reshape2)
```

> fill - value with which to fill in structural missings, defaults to value from applying fun.aggregate to 0 length vector

```
dcast(df, x ~ y, value.var = "z", fun.aggregate = NULL)
# x  A  B  C  D
#1 1  3  2  1 NA
#2 2  4  2 NA NA
#3 3  3  2 NA  1
#4 4 NA  2 NA NA
#5 5 NA NA  3  4

dcast(df, x ~ y, value.var = "z", fun.aggregate = sum)
#  x A B C D
#1 1 3 2 1 0
#2 2 4 2 0 0
#3 3 3 2 0 1
#4 4 0 2 0 0
#5 5 0 0 3 4
```

Note that here is there is only one element per combination, so the `sum` will return the same value except that if there is a particular combination not preseent, it return 0.  It is based on the behavior of `sum`

```
length(integer(0))
#[1] 0
sum(integer(0))
#[1] 0

sum(NULL)
#[1] 0
```

Or when all the elements are `NA` and if we use `na.rm`, there won't be any element to sum, then also it goees into `integer(0)` mode

```
sum(c(NA, NA), na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 0
```

If we use `sum_` from `hablar`, this behavior is changed to return `NA`

```
library(hablar)
sum_(c(NA, NA))
#[1] NA
```

---

An option is to create a condition in the `fun.aggregate` to return `NA`

```
dcast(df, x ~ y, value.var = "z", 
   fun.aggregate = function(x) if(length(x) == 0) NA_real_ else sum(x, na.rm = TRUE))
#  x  A  B  C  D
#1 1  3  2  1 NA
#2 2  4  2 NA NA
#3 3  3  2 NA  1
#4 4 NA  2 NA NA
#5 5 NA NA  3  4
```

For more info about how the `sum` (primitive function) is created, check the source code [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/summary.c)